# Received memory warning in camera UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, memory, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

when i enter to the camera UIImagePickerController i get sometime a memory warning message and i don't know how to fix this.

this is my code:

```
    -(IBAction)addImageCamera:(id)sender
    {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            pickerImgCamera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            cameraView.image=[img imageFromMainBundleFile:@"frameCam.png"];
            pickerImgCamera.cameraOverlayView=cameraView;

            [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:pickerImgCamera animated:NO];

        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView*alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:@"Camera not found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
            alert=nil;
        }
    }


 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
        {
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

            });
        }

        [photoImage setImage:image];
    }
```

note: the memory warning appear in iphone and ipad.

Comment: what is the memory warning? could you post it here?

Comment: I get "[1777:907] Received memory warning." that's it. the number change every time...

Comment: try `command + shift + B` tell me if it display something.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the iPhone camera triggers memory warnings frequently, especially on older devices. It's more likely to happen when you're debugging - the trick is handling the warning & getting rid of stuff which isn't essential.

Answer (score -2):

if image quality is not so important in your app, then set videoQuality of the uiimagepickercontroller to UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow. This will reduce teh memory warning in the application.

Comment: also, its a horrible idea.